# Get a List of all patients examinations sorted by date of examination grouped by patient newest first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to extract a list of all examinations sorted by date of examination (DESC) and 'grouped' (in a non-SQL term) by Patient

So if this is my table

```
Id  DateOfExamination   PatientId   Text
1   2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter     
2   2018-02-03 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies   
3   2019-05-04 00:00:00.0000000 3   Sonja     
4   2017-02-09 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter     
5   2016-02-03 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies   
6   2017-03-04 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter     
7   2014-04-05 00:00:00.0000000 3   Sonja     
8   2018-03-04 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies
```

This is what I need

```
Id  DateOfExamination   PatientId   Text
3   2019-05-04 00:00:00.0000000 3   Sonja     
7   2014-04-05 00:00:00.0000000 3   Sonja     
1   2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter     
4   2017-02-09 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter     
6   2017-03-04 00:00:00.0000000 1   Peter    
8   2018-03-04 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies   
2   2018-02-03 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies   
5   2016-02-03 00:00:00.0000000 2   Marlies
```

The youngest examination goes first, followed by all other examinations of that patient. Then the next 'youngest' examination and that patients older ince. And so far.

Every examination should be listed only once.

I am a beginner in SQL, so what I tried so far will not really help.

Comment: Regardless of how *bad* you think your query is, please always post it - that way we know what you have tried and what you need help with - otherwise it seems like you're just asking us to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to order by patients, but with the caveat that you want the youngest exam first.

The simplest way to do this uses window functions in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by max(t.DateOfExamination) over (partition by t.patientId) desc,
         t.patientId,  -- to handle ties
         t.DateOfExamination desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0909cb2692a2b284357c8102ecf0c58e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you

Thats not exactly what I need

In words I want a list of the patients that where examined - the latest examination first - and I want all older examinations of that patients to be listed under the current examination before I get the next examination of the next patient done today - with his older examinations listed after that.

Comment: @Schlomo . . . Have you run this query?  That is what this query does.

Comment: Sorry Gordon. After trying 2h on the real data. Your statement is correct but returns the data in the wrong order. 
The patients with the youngest examination show up on the bottom of the list and the patients who's last examination was the longest time ago show up on the top of the list. Can you help me to get the right order?
The patient that had his Examination 10mins ago should be the first on the list followed by his older examinations and the patient that was here 30 mins ago should follow after that. I am sorry to repeat myself.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Schlomo . . . The first key just needs to be a descending sort.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will do it for you:

```
with cte1(Id, DateOfExamination, PatientId, Text, seqnum, maxdoe) as
(
select Id, DateOfExamination, PatientId, Text,
    row_number() over(partition by PatientId order by DateOfExamination desc) seqnum,
    max(DateOfExamination) over(partition by PatientId order by (select null)) maxdoe
from mytable
)
select Id, DateOfExamination, PatientId, Text
from cte1
order by maxdoe desc, seqnum
```

Comment: @Schlomo Happy to be of help. You can give it a thumbs up by upvoting on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CTE that gets the newest for each patient and then join this with the table and manage the sorting based on both.

```
with cte as ( 
    select t.PatientId, max(dateofexamination) as dateofexamination
    from t
    group by t.PatientId
) 
select t2.*
from cte as t
    inner join t as t2 ON t.PatientId = t2.PatientId
order by t.dateofexamination desc, t2.PatientID desc, t2.dateofexamination desc
```

Comment: If two patients had their newest exams on the same date, their rows will be intermingled unless you change the ORDER BY clause to `t.dateofexamination desc, t2.PatientId.desc, t2.dateofexamination desc`

Comment: The label t should not be used for the CTE if it is also the name of the original table.

Comment: You were right in regards to the order by. But in regards to the label t, there is no problem using it there, SQL will not confuse them because it will recognize them as being two separate selects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do use **GROUP BY** clause and **MAX()** aggregate function to get highest date patient id wise.

After that you need to use that select query in CROSS APPLY with Patient ID column.

To get your expected result from CROSS APPLY table you need to do use **ORDER BY** clause on MAX DateOfExamination value column as desc of group by select query table and DateOfExamination column as desc of CROSS APPLY table.

Please check below query for your expected answer.

```
SELECT 
    d.ID,
    d.DateOfExamination,
    d.PatientId,
    d.[Text]
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        PatientId, 
        MAX(DateOfExamination) DateOfExam
    FROM #tblA
    GROUP BY PatientId
) t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
        P.ID,
        P.DateOfExamination,
        P.PatientId,
        P.[Text]
    FROM #tblA p 
    WHERE p.PatientId = t.PatientId 
) d
ORDER BY t.DateOfExam DESC,d.DateOfExamination DESC

DROP TABLE #tblA;
```

Check this [link](https://rextester.com/RKYN12078) to test above query.